# remove whitespace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, whitespace

I want to remove whitespace in `input.value` but the replace method dosent work for me, I searched online but I couldn't figure it out why is that

I tried to remove whitespace with replace method, this is my code:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    inputValidation();

})

function inputValidation(){
    for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', () => {
            const errorImg = document.querySelectorAll('.error-img');
            const errorMassage = document.querySelectorAll('.label');
            const emailRegX = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/
            const passwordRegX = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$/;
            
            if (inputs[i].value !== "") {
                inputs[i].value.replace(/\s/g, "");
}
```

Also I tried add this line `inputs[i].value.replace(/\s/g, "");` above if statement, that dosent work neither.I want to not able to add any whitespace

Comment: `inputs[i].value.replace(/\s/g, "");` **returns** the modified string, which you ignore - try `inputs[i].value = inputs[i].value.replace(/\s/g, "");`

Comment: [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) doesn't work in place (ie doesn't modify the string it's called on) but returns a new string with the replacements done. You are not using this result.

Comment: rather than trying to replace white space, isn't it easier to give a warning to user that space is not allowed? I mean if someone is using white space like a normal person, maybe they can be warned about it instead of their text to be altered?

Comment: Thanks for your help, that was the solution, inputs[i].value = inputs[i].value.replace(/\s/g, ""); @jaromanda